# Google Sheets API with Flask - setting the row index from my view

Tags: python, flask, google-sheets-api

I'm working towards storing input from a template into a Google Sheet as a viewable database. I've gotten my view to a point where I can input data into the Sheet from my Flask template, but this requires me to set a static reference to which index and row the data should be placed in.

Here's the view I am working with:

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
row = [str(request.form['name']), str(request.form['email']), str(request.form['textBox'])]
index = 1
sheet.insert_row(row, index)
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Note the sheet_insert_row(row, index). I am able to snag the input from the forms in the template to place into my row variable, but I'm not sure of how to dynamically input the index variable.

I've tried:

```
index = sheet.row_count+1
```

But this, unfortunately, counts all rows, regardless of whether they are filled or not. Is there a way to manipulate this method to only work on rows with values?

Comment: What library are you using to connect to the API?

Comment: @LuisOrduz Sorry, I forgot to include that. I am using gspread (https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @LuisOrduz append_row works so far as I can tell, not sure why you deleted your answer, but thank you.

Comment: Really? I was checking the implementation and append_row does what you're already doing. Are you sure it isn't creating the row after a lot of empty ones? I undeleted anyway, but insert_row calls append_row anyway when you set index to row_count+1. Weird.

Comment: @LuisOrduz Ah...you're right actually. It is.

Comment: Thought so, deleted again hehe. I'm reading the documentation of the API for a way to get the last filled row.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some sort of unique index to the "next" row after each insert. Add '######' to the first column of the next row when you insert, and then you can locate it using find(), or findall() if you want to validate that someone hasn't inserted that...best practice would be to filter that from being inserted in your Python.

I'd recommend an actual database...even if you're in an environment where everyone loves excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use service.spreadsheets().values()**.append()**

From https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

```
def append_to_gsheet(output_data=[], gsheet_id = args.gsheet_id, range_name = RANGE_NAME):
    # Setup the Sheets API
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    # Call the Sheets API
    body = {
        'values': output_data
    }
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=gsheet_id, range=range_name,
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
    print('{0} rows updated.'.format(DictQuery(result).get('updates/updatedRows')))
```